# OpenZeppelin Context.sol smart contract is abstract, why?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, abstract

I was digging into this OZ smart contract:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol

As you may see, it has only two functions to deal with metatxs. I can't figure out why this contract is defined as abstract, as both functions are implemented. Thanks in advance to all of you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an instance of an abstract contract (with something like `Context a = new Context();`). So it's probably defined as abstract so it can't be deployed on its own - it has to be inherited. Deploying just the Context contract wouldn't make much sense anyway.

Wherever it's in use, it's part of an inheritance.